# Find all mysql rows from last month with unixtimestamp

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a better way of selecting all rows created in the previous month. Currently I am just going back x number of days, but I want it to run on the 1st of every month, and don't want to have to keep adjusting it.

Essentially, I just want it to select from the "date" field where the month is the previous month.

Here is my current sql:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.article_id, a.date, a.tagline_image, a.article_top_image_filename, a.title, a.tagline, a.views, c.category_id
    FROM 
        articles a
    LEFT JOIN 
        `article_category_reference` c ON a.article_id = c.article_id
    WHERE 
        a.date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 33 DAY)) AND c.category_id NOT IN (63) AND a.active = 1 group by `a`.`article_id`
    ORDER BY 
        a.views DESC
    LIMIT 30
     ) a
ORDER BY views ASC
```

Comment: might want to look into `mysql create event` functionality to have it mechanized at some point. One can specify start datetime, and interval. Interval can range from 1 second, to annually. Data output could be sitting in your inbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that ?

```
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.date)) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Comment: Good ! Please mark your question as solved, and this as accepted answer so that other people won't lose time trying to answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

A good strategy is to get the first day of the last month by calculating the last day of the month before that and then adding 1 day:

```
 a.date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Comment: That still gave me stuff from today.